# DNS configuration between external domain name and loadbalancer/services in Rancher

Tags: dns, rancher

I would like to configure my external domain name to my load balancer in rancher.

I have a domain name `mydomain.com` via loopia.com

I have Load balancer in Rancher with FQDN: `lb.lb.tothis.com`
and within the Load Balancer, I have setup the rules with request host to be `mydomain.com` and point to a target container within Rancher.

At this point, I'm not sure how to set it correctly.
I've tried to setup A Record at root dns (@) and www using one of the IP that return from `lb.lb.tothis.com` using this https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#A/
but it seems it does not work

I have tried to set CName in wildcard * that point to  `lb.lb.tothis.com` but it also does not help either.

What do I miss to configure to make this work?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should first point to the IP of the node where your service is running and then in the firewall that is in front of your network you should create a NAT and DNAT rule to canalize the traffic to the node.